# How to design a simple page cache?

Tags: php, mysql, json, apache, lamp

I would like to limit the number of times a page is generated in a certain time frame, but am unsure of how to even approach the problem.

Previously, I have solved similar problems by scheduling the pages to be generated and saved in a cron job, but this will not allow me to do this dynamically.

Here is the scenario:

I have `n` number of user created rooms. I would like to build a JSON api to allow the users to access room information for use on their own pages. However, generating a new JSON result for every request would be extremely inefficient and impose security risks on the database server. I would like to limit it, so that all requests in `x` amount of time use the same JSON result rather than new results each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a  simple caching system can be done like this

```
 if (!file_exists($cacheFile) || filemtime($cacheFile) - time() > $cacheLifetime){
     //generate json and save to $cacheFile
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 header("Content-Length: ".filesize($cacheFile));
 readfile($cacheFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a typical use case for a cache.

The general algorithm is (when a resource is requested):

```
if (resource is cached) {
    return cached contents
} else {
    construct the resource
    store resource in cache
    return the resource
}
```

If you want to implement a time-based invalidation, the algorithm becomes:

```
if (resource is cached) {
    if (cached resource older than threshold) {
        remove resource from cache
    } else {
        return cached contents
    }
}
construct the resource
store resource in cache
return the resource
```

The "age" of the cached contents is calculated from the date of creation of this content, that you need to store along with the cache entry.

Depending on how dynamic your users web-sites are, you may also want to *not* regenerate the JSON if "nothing has changed" since the last generation. Your algorithm would then become:

```
if (resource is cached) {
    if (cached resource older than threshold AND something changed) {
        remove resource from cache
    } else {
        return cached contents
    }
}
...
```

The meaning of "nothing / something has changed" is up to you, it could be the user posts new contents, or some statistics are updated or whatever is used to build your resource. Set a flag on the cache when such an event happens.

The cache can take any form: a flat file on the server, a database row, a session variable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database to cache the json strings (dont forget a timestamp). Then you are able to search your database first and provide the already generated JSON-string :)